# Header file not working (source file not compiled) c language

Tags: c

In my header file file.h I have:

```
#ifdef FILE_H
extern "C" {
#endif

int size;
int array[3];
    
void saveToFile();
void loadFromFile();

#ifdef FILE_H
}
#endif
```

After I try compiling it, table with "Source file not compiled" pops up and I also get warning like this command line option '-std=c99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++.

In my file.c I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "file.h"

void saveToFile(){
    FILE *load=fopen("1uzd.txt", "w");
    int array[3];
    fprintf(load, "%d ", 3);
    array[0]=1;
    array[1]=2;
    array[2]=3;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        fprintf(load, "%d ", array[i]);
    }
    fclose(load);
}
void loadFromFile(){
    FILE *load=fopen("1uzd.txt", "r");
    int size;
    fscanf(load, "%d", &size);
    int array[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        fscanf(load, "%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", size, array[0], array[1]);
}
```

And undefined reference to `WinMain' with ld returned 1 exit status
And in main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file.h"
int main(void){
    saveToFile();
    loadFromFile();
    return 0;
}
```

With undefined reference to `saveToFile', undefined reference to` loadFromFile' and ld returned 1 exit status.

Answer (score 2):

> In my header file file.h I have:
>
> ```
> #ifdef FILE_H
> extern "C" {
> #endif
>
> int size;
> int array[3];
>     
> void saveToFile();
> void loadFromFile();
>
> #ifdef FILE_H
> }
> #endif
> ```

Your multi-inclusion guards have the wrong sense and scope.  Also, if your intention is for this header to be usable in both C and C++, then the `extern "C"` declaration is incorrectly protected.  Perhaps you want this:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int size;
int array[3];
    
void saveToFile();
void loadFromFile();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

That provides for

- the contents of the header to be considered only the first time the header is included in any translation unit, and
- the `extern "C"` declaration to be ignored unless the header is being processed by a C++ compiler.

> After I try compiling it, table with "Source file not compiled" pops
> up and I also get warning like this command line option '-std=c99' is
> valid for C/ObjC but not for C++.

One does not compile headers directly.  One uses `#include` directives to incorporate their contents into other sources.  The source files you present contain such `#include` directives, so you should not need to do anything further in that regard.

> In my file.c I have [...]  undefined reference to `WinMain'

You are trying to compile file.c as a complete program, but that doesn't work because it does not have a `main()` function.

> And in main.c [...] undefined reference to saveToFile', undefined reference to loadFromFile'

You are trying to compile `main.c` as a complete program, but it does not contain the source of a complete program because it calls functions that are defined in a different source file.

There are two main approaches you could take:

1. compile each .c file to an object file and then link them together into a whole program in a separate step, or
2. compile both .c files in a single compilation command.

Details of both options depend on the compiler and build system used.  Some of your diagnostic messages suggest GCC to me, and with GCC running in command-line mode, the latter would be something like

```
gcc -std=c99 -o my_program.exe main.c file.c
```

.  The "my_program.exe" is the name you want your executable to have.  The `-std=c99` is necessary with your code for some versions of GCC, and the diagnostics suggest that it appears in the command-line arguments you are actually using.  You may include other command-line options, too, if you wish.

Note also that you must use a C compiler to compile C code, not a C++ compiler.  Your diagnostics suggest that you may be trying to use the latter.  C and C++ are different languages.  Although they have a shared subset, neither is a superset of the other.